# How can assign role to registered user using laravel 8 +jetstream + spatie

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I've created roles using spatie. I want to let jetstream register form assign role 'gust' to any user registered via jetstream register form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by going to: app>actions>Fortify>CreateNewUser.php>

```
public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
        ])->validate();

        return DB::transaction(function () use ($input) {
            return tap(User::create([
                'name' => $input['name'],
                'email' => $input['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            ]), function (User $user) {
                $this->createRole($user);
            });
        });
    }
```

then I've created a protected function createRole as follows:

```
protected function createRole(User $user)
    {
        $user->assignRole('geust');
    }
```

Which automatically assign a role to newly registered user.
don't forget to add the following directives to the top of the file:

```
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
```

Second directive in case if you want to assign a permission as well.